# Constructing a finite automaton to prove L is regular

Tags: regex, finite-automata, automata

```
Considering a language L, let L′ be the set of all first halves of strings in L so that

L′ ={x| for some y,|x|=|y|and xy ∈ L}

Please prove that if L is regular, then L′ is also regular by constructing a finite
automaton for L′.
```

I am having some difficulty tackling this problem.  I've seen a few solutions but would like to have someone explain, in layman's terms, how this problem should be solved.  I've reviewed the solution on problem 11 from the following link:  http://tuvalu.santafe.edu/~moore/theory/hw1solns.pdf.

From my understanding, both a DFA for L and NFA for L' must be constructed, and within L' we track the final state of L as well as the backwards path from the final state.  I appreciate the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this proof, you don't have to construct a DFA for `L`. Your premise is that `L` is regular, so you know that there *exists* a DFA for `L`. Choose any, and now you can *construct* a NFA for `L'`, by running your `L` DFA parallel to a copy of it that operates backwards.